# What is a "New Tab"?

Tags: unity, chromium

Sorry for the length of my question but I don't know a lot of the terminology of the steps of my explanation. I'm a senior and not very computer literate. When I log in and before I click on my Chromium browser, one of the icons on my screen says "Home". When I click on it a menu pops up and it gives me choices from Home down to Network. After I choose videos for example and click on "File" at the top left of my screen the first choice is "New Tab". I know what a tab does on a keyboard, but what is a "Tab" (written & visual), when & why would I need a "New Tab". Please try to explain in simple terms and/or pictures if you can. Thank you

Comment: Open something "in a new tab", and you'll see it yourself.

Comment: Think of the old fashioned [tabbed file folders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_folder#Tabbed_file_folders) or tabbed dividers / index cards used in paper record keeping

Answer (score 2):

A `Tab` in a browser window is just like a mini-browser which can load/open a website. `Tabs` are there to open multiple websites in browser concurrently(at the same time). For example you open browser and open https://example.com on start. Now you want to play background music while you read content of https://example.com You would open a new tab and load a website https://spotify.com in that tab. Now you have both websites open and you can switch between them.

See this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tabs-organize-websites-single-window

Comment: Please provide images!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Mozilla link guide include images.

Comment: And if the link goes dead what will we do?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen you're right but you know it is not a matter to provide extra images to explain. It added what was enough

Comment: Control-T will open a new tab. Do that and see what happens.